# Integration of certain real functions using Euler's Formula.

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I've heard about using Euler's formula $$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$ to transform rational functions of sine and cosine into computable indefinite integrals. However, upon attempting to apply this myself, I ran into some trouble. I'm asking for someone to give a run-down of the method and idea, specifically I need help with the following integral $$\int \frac{a+\sin(x)}{b+\cos(x)} {dx}$$ My attempt to use THIS method to solve this integral is as follows. First, I recognized that $$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}=-i\sinh(ix)$$ and $$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}=\cosh(ix)$$ then I set $u=e^{ix}$ so ${du}=ie^{ix} \ {dx}=iu \ {dx}$ and finally arrived at the following expression in terms of u $$-\int\frac{u^2+2aiu-1}{u^3+2bu^2+u}{du}$$ I am not sure how to proceed from here, my only idea is polynomial long division and I hesitate to undertake such a messy path if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: Could we see your attempt at solution?

Comment: Sure, give me a couple minutes to type it all out, but I'm not sure I understand your second sentence.

Comment: I was just wondering why you think this example is a good candidate for applying Euler's formula....I deleted that other sentence, it didn't come out right.

Comment: I thought this integral was a perfect example of a general rational function of sine and cosine.

Comment: It may be a little "pedantic" but before trig functions you should put a \, so that \$\sin(x)\$ renders as $\sin(x)$ instead of $sin(x)$... I would just quickly toss it in there for you, but I don't want to disturb any lengthy edits you may be making at the moment.

Comment: I appreciate it Travis! I'm somewhat new to MathJax (meaning I first used it today)

Comment: Now that I see your attempt. I'd use partial fractions and polynomial division. Keep in mind that the fraction can be split into 3 parts before doing the above.